# How to pass variables to helm install --set parameters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I want to know if it is possible to pass variables to an `helm install` command's set parameter. Below is an example of what I'm looking to achieve.

```
appgw_name = "myappgateway"
export appgw_name
helm install applicationgw application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-azure --set appgw.name=$appgw_name
```

I'm executing the above two lines as a shell script and when I try to execute them I get the below error:

> Error: execution error at (ingress-azure/templates/configmap.yaml):
>   Please either provide appgw.applicationGatewayID or appgw.name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. Was just a few spacings that had to be altered. The issue was with bash and had nothing to do with helm. So this is how I finally declared the variables `export appgw_name="myappgateway"` Just removed all the spaces and that's it. It worked like charm.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter will be resolved by your shell. If you write these directly from the command line you need to either export the env variable or execute then together in one line.

Try this:

```
export appgw_name="myappgateway"
helm install applicationgw application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-azure --set appgw.name=${appgw_name}
```

Comment: tried that too. Didn't work out. I'll add this to the question too.

Comment: Why not just `--set appgw.name=myappgateway`

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I'm executing this command as a part of one big script. So hardcoding things is not a good idea. However I don't even know whether this is possible. So if it is not then probably will resort to what you suggested

Comment: `foo=bar; export foo` is valid Bourne shell syntax and will result in an exported environment variable, the same as if you did `export foo=bar`.